# Can my managers deny training time due to busy hours?

Tags: raise, training

I was hired at my current job and as per policy, I should receive a $1/hr raise after 6 months as long as all my training is done. I have just passed my 6 months but have not completed all of the training, and I also found out the managers are purposely not allowing anyone to complete training for the next month due to busy store hours.

I have to be clocked in to do the training and when we do training is up to the supervisor's discretion. This is a cashier position and they'd like us to be working rather than training.  I fear that management is purposefully preventing me from completing my training so that they do not have to give me the raise.

I have done my best to complete this training.  After some modules it requires approval from management to take further modules.  It has taken 30-40 days to get these approvals so far.

How should I address this situation with my manager/supervisor?

Comment: If this is just a holiday thing I get it.  If from the beginning if it has taken 30-40 days to get these approvals then that sound like intentional delays.  Still probably not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Who made the promise/policy about the $1/hr raise after 6 months?

If this policy came from the owner (assuming owner is different than manager in this case) or corporate, then they may have a view on your current problem and are likely the only ones who can force your managers to comply with it.  They can investigate to determine if the reasons why the managers are not allowing the training are valid or not and if not possibly take action.  If they choose to ignore your complaint/concern then you are stuck.

**Be warned.**  If you involve a higher level in this regardless of whether they take action or not, your managers may attempt to retaliate against you (even if it is banned by policy or by law).  So if that does occur you will have to be ready for a second round of fighting or be ready to find another job.

If this policy/promise came from the managers then they can caveat the promise/policy however they wish to the point that it becomes hollowed of any value or meaning.  At this point you can suck it up as a bad promise that they likely will not deliver on, or begin looking for a different place that values you.

Comment: The raise does come from corporate and was originally part of the hiring terms so I'll talk to someone about it.

Comment: +1 Talking to corporate is often the only way to resolve these kinds of issues.